# What {% %} and {{ }} mean in HTML?

Tags: python, html, django

I have recently started to learn Django, so I came across with some HTML templates, but those are pretty unfamiliar for me, they mostly consist of {% and {{

For example:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

What are they? Implementations from other languages or HTML syntax? I'd be happy to get some docs, websites or examples too.

Comment: They are called Django Template Language. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/

Comment: It's Jinja2, you'll need to familiarize with it in order to use Django properly.

Comment: First try googling stuff yourself.
Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You mentioned to have "started to learn Django". When you state "learn" I would assume  tutorials, studying the documentation and Hello World examples. If this is not your approach I can only recommend it to you.

Answer (score 1):

The {% _________ %} are template tags. They are used to interpolate a tag into the space. Examples include `extend`, `include`, and `load` to name but a few. They often extend, insert, or give some sort logical functionality in some way (if conditions or loops, etc).

The {{ ___________ }} syntax is for template variables. This is used to interpolate a variable declared either as one of the built-in options or your own which you have created from any number of methods (models, view context, etc).

The Django docs are pretty thorough with use cases of all these. Another website which shortlists these to make them readily understandable is https://www.djangotemplatetagsandfilters.com/

Comment: Aren't template variables in form  {{ _____ }}   ?

Comment: Yep, you're right. Double curly braces on each side. I'll edit the answer to reflect that for others.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean anything in html itself, it means something in Django template language. For example:

```
{{ choice.choice_text }}
```

will substitute value of that variable during template rendering.

The other one {% and %} is used for template processing, for example to indicate to template processor that some task needs to be completed. Good example is:

```
{% if error %}
    {{ error }}
{% endif %}
```

That means that the variable error will be displayed (rendered) only if it exists, or to be more precise if it has some value.

Answer (score 0):

The ones you are referring are jinja codes. They are very essential to work with Django and also they easy to understand when you have general understanding about python and django. You can find the documentation about jinga in this URL [Jinja2 Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)